# In a form, I want subsequent fields depending upon previous field?

Tags: forms

I have an entity creation form and I have a radio button as a field. Now what I need is, if while adding the entity, if radio button is set, then one more field just below should appear otherwise not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If looking for a module, you can use the D7 -dev version of [conditional_fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.
>
> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new States
>   API, plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on
>   certain conditions when viewing content.

Alternatively, you can tweak the forms directly in code using [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and the [States API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7)

In this example, I show the UPC field when the specified operation value is chosen in a select box:

```
  // Define available batch operation callbacks
  $operations = array(
    'infinity_batch_sync_products' => 'Import and sync product details',
    'infinity_fetch_products' => 'Fetch list of available products',
    'infinity_fetch_product' => 'Fetch detail on single product'
  );

  $form['operation'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select operation'),
    '#options' => $operations,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['upc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('UPC'),
    '#description' => t('Enter the product UPC code (commerce product SKU)'),
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
       ':input[name="operation"]' => array('value' => 'infinity_fetch_product'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

The "UPC" field only shows when the operation is "infinity_fetch_product"

Comment: no i am not looking for a module. I am writing code and want to achieve this through code.Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer.And i want that additional field during the creating the entity i.e before saving the entity.

Comment: @neetumorwani answer updated with states api example.